# Need help converting C# to F#

Tags: f#

I'd like to know how to convert this code line by line from C# to F#. I am not looking to use any kind of F#'s idioms or something of the like. I am trying to understand how to enumaration and reflcetion in F#.

```
using System.Linq;

namespace System.Collections.Generic
{
    public static class EnumerableExtensions
    {
        private static readonly Random random;
        static EnumerableExtensions()
        {
            random = new Random();
        }
        public static T Random<T>(this IEnumerable<T> input)
        {
            return input.ElementAt(random.Next(input.Count()));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your random variable should have `[ThreadStatic]` as an attribute to make the code safe for a multithreading situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define extensions as static methods in a type, but you have to mark those with the `Extension` attribute. A direct rewrite of your C# code would be:

```
open System.Runtime.CompilerServices

[<Extension>]
type EnumerableExtensions() =
  static let rnd = System.Random()
  [<Extension>]
  static member Random(input:seq<_>) = 
    input |> Seq.item (rnd.Next(Seq.length input))

[1;2;3].Random()
```